# Regex only captures some data, not all of them

Tags: regex, gawk

I'm trying to use regex to capture some data from the following lines:

```
[*] 0.0.0.0:80 Cannot reliably check exploitability.

[-] {peer} - Check failed: The following options failed to validate: USERNAME, PASSWORD.

[*] 0.0.0.0:80 The target is not exploitable.
```

The regex I'm using is:

```
^\[.\].*\s([A-Z]{1}.*$)
```

The problem is that it results in (for the capture group):

```
Cannot reliably check exploitability.
PASSWORD.
The target is not exploitable.
```

What I want to capture is the all the text, it works for for the ones that has ip's in them but the other one it kinda flops on, what I need the middle one to be is:

```
Check failed: The following options failed to validate: USERNAME, PASSWORD.
```

I'm not sure why it won't capture the middle one properly.

This is for gawk, if that's important.

Comment: Try `^\[.\][^A-Z]*\s([A-Z].*$)`

Comment: `gawk` is just an implementation of `awk`. If you tag your questions with `awk` in addition to `gawk` you'll get vastly more people reading them and get multiple answers almost immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is not working properly due to the greedy `.*` pattern that makes the regex match up to the last uppercase letter after a whitespace.

You may use a `[^A-Z]*` instead of the `.*`:

```
^\[.\][^A-Z]*\s([A-Z].*)$
      ^^^^^^^
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of the line
- `\[` - a `[`
- `.` - any char
- `\]` - a `]`
- `[^A-Z]*` - any 0+ chars other than ASCII uppercase letters
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `([A-Z].*)` - Group 1: an uppercase ASCII letter and the rest of the line
- `$` - end of line